# MYSQL: get ranking position over a "history" table with messages

Tags: mysql, ranking

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/523ffa/1

I have a history table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `history_id` int(6),
  `date_added` datetime,
  `message` varchar(200),
  `user_id` int(6)
);
```

This table is populated by messages that user posts on a specific Slack channel.

Now I want to get statistics from it, I want to know what date had the most messages posted, a long with the user who did post the most messages & the date itself.

I have created this query, but I cannot seem to implement the 'rank' in it:

```
SELECT b.cnt as dayCount, a.cnt as userCount, a.userId, b.date as dateStr, u.name as userName
            FROM ( 
                   select date_format(date_added, "%d/%m/%Y") as date, user_id as userid, count(*) as cnt from history group by userid, date_format(date_added, "%d/%m/%Y") order by cnt 
                 ) a 
            INNER JOIN ( 
                   select date_format(date_added, "%d/%m/%Y") as date, count(*) as cnt from history group by date_format(date_added, "%d/%m/%Y") 
                 ) b ON a.date = b.date 
            INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = a.userid 
            GROUP BY a.userId, b.date 
            ORDER BY dayCount desc, userCount desc;
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+------------+----------------------+
| dayCount | userCount | userId | dateStr    | userName             |
+----------+-----------+--------+------------+----------------------+
|     2308 |       842 |      1 | 20/03/2018 | user1                |
|     2308 |       640 |      4 | 20/03/2018 | user4                |
|     2308 |       438 |      6 | 20/03/2018 | user6                |
|     2308 |       288 |      5 | 20/03/2018 | user5                |
|     2308 |        78 |      2 | 20/03/2018 | user2                |
|     2308 |        22 |      3 | 20/03/2018 | user3                |
|     1771 |       672 |      1 | 14/10/2019 | user1                |
|     1771 |       452 |      6 | 14/10/2019 | user6                |
|     1771 |       405 |      4 | 14/10/2019 | user4                |
|     1771 |       189 |      5 | 14/10/2019 | user5                |
|     1771 |        37 |      2 | 14/10/2019 | user2                |
|     1771 |        16 |      3 | 14/10/2019 | user3                |
```

After the column userName there should be a column with the rank of that represents the ranking position of the date over the entire resultset, for daycount 2308 this should be 1, for 1771 this should be 2, ...

Wanted result:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+------------+----------------------+--------------+
| dayCount | userCount | userId | dateStr    | userName             |   rank       |
+----------+-----------+--------+------------+----------------------+--------------+
|     2308 |       842 |      1 | 20/03/2018 | user1                |  1           |
|     2308 |       640 |      4 | 20/03/2018 | user4                |  1           |
|     2308 |       438 |      6 | 20/03/2018 | user6                |  1           |
|     2308 |       288 |      5 | 20/03/2018 | user5                |  1           |
|     2308 |        78 |      2 | 20/03/2018 | user2                |  1           |
|     2308 |        22 |      3 | 20/03/2018 | user3                |  1           |
|     1771 |       672 |      1 | 14/10/2019 | user1                |  2           |
|     1771 |       452 |      6 | 14/10/2019 | user6                |  2           |
|     1771 |       405 |      4 | 14/10/2019 | user4                |  2           |
|     1771 |       189 |      5 | 14/10/2019 | user5                |  2           |
|     1771 |        37 |      2 | 14/10/2019 | user2                |  2           |
|     1771 |        16 |      3 | 14/10/2019 | user3                |  2           |
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach this? For example, having 260.000 entries in history table the query itself takes 0.6s.

thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) (You are perhaps one-third of the way there)

Comment: I've added a SQLFiddle, hope its clear now

Comment: Does the fiddle include the desired result?

Comment: Added in the main post

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: using mysql 8.0

Comment: See for instance; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/523ffa/2 - but (as written) this solution won't work in MySQL 8+, where you'd anyway be better advised to use windowing functions.

Comment: @Strawberry why won't it work as written in MySQL 8+?

Comment: Because I used a lazy syntax, but one that older versions of MySQL forgives. You can adapt this solution to MySQL 8+ (and it would still work in older versions too), but you just have to put the ORDER BY clause somewhere else.

Comment: I'm indeed getting following error:    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank, @prev:= daycount prev FROM
( SELECT b.cnt as dayCount, a.cnt as userCount,' at line 1